# How to find file under device file explorer

Tags: sqlite, file, android-studio, device, explorer

As pretext, I have been following the an Android Studio Tutorial by ProgrammingKnowledge, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8TaTgr4uKM. But am stuck around the 9:22 mark. I am trying to find my folder under device file explorer> data > data as he did but to no success.

[image: sqllitedirectory]

I am using android version 3.5.3. Any advice or solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am 99% sure that the application folder is there. You just have to search for it.

In my case, the application ID is **com.iyfuture.peddypaper**. So I search inside the device file explorer a folder that haves this exact name.

[image]

Personally I recommend you to always **synchronize** the device file explorer before doing any type of search. You can achieve it like this:

- Inside the device explorer **press** the **right mouse button** in the folder or file you want;
- After pressing it you will see a list that will have the **synchronize option**. Select it.

This way you guarantee that every folder and file are updated (before any changes you or the application might do).**One last thing, make sure that the emulator you are using is running and that is exactly the same that appears on TOP of the device file explorer.**